# clear text input on another controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

is it possible to clear all fields in one controller by clicking on a button from the previous controller?

I'm trying to do so by setting cache:  false in routes.js in the controller that needs to be cleared, however, I realized that it clears the controller's fields every time it's loaded.

I need to be able to clear the fields of the pages once a user clicks on login, however, I also need to be able to go back to the previous pages once I enter the "review info" page.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ionic version-1 framework, then use
`$scope.logout = function(){
    // first, clear the history
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    // clear the cache before you navigate to a page
    $ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function(){
      $state.go("app.login");
    });
 }`